# How to execute shiny modules in a sequential manner?

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to build an app with shiny modules. These modules need to be executed in a sequential manner and each module builds on the same object such as the example below:

```
QG <- callModule(loadInput, "first")
QG <- callModule(addParameter, "second", QG) 
QG <- callModule(analyze, "third",  QG)
```

I wrap the return values with reactive expression and I tried having a unique name for each module output (example below) but it doesn’t' work.

```
QG1 <- callModule(loadInput, "first")
QG2 <- callModule(addParameter, "second", QG1) 
QG3 <- callModule(analyze, "third",  QG2)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @michaelmccarthy404 is right. You need to provide more details about what your modules do in order to get raseonable answers about this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to solve this problem without having the full app available to test with, but this is the logic that I would use in solving the issue:

```
values <- reactiveValues(
  QG1 = NULL,
  QG2 = NULL,
  QG3 = NULL
)

values$QG1 <- callModule(loadInput, "first")

observeEvent(values$QG1, {
  values$QG2 <- callModule(addParameter, "second", values$QG1)
})

observeEvent(values$QG2, {
  values$QG3 <- callModule(analyze, "third", values$QG2)
})
```

In the first block we create multiple reactive values that will hold the output of each of the modules. We initialize each of these to `NULL` as `NULL` is ignored by default by `observeEvent()`.

Next we can call the first module and set it's returned result to `values$QG1`. `loadInput` doesn't need to return a reactive expression, infact, I wouldn't have any of the modules return reactive expressions. When the value of `values$QG1` is changed, the first `observeEvent()` will be triggered which in turn changes the value of `values$QG2`. Finally, the change of the value of `values$QG2` will trigger the second `observeEvent()` which ultimately returns it's value to `values$QG3`.

Comment: I don't think it is a good iead to use `callModule` inside a reactive expression for the same reason you don't want to put `renderPlot` in such a context. `callModule` is supposed to be called once for each module in an app.